# The Compressonator convert dds to png with alpha channel

Tags: png, alpha, directdraw, dds-format

What is the command for converting dds to png with alpha channel?

If I use this command:

```
TheCompressonator.exe -convert -r .\dds .\out -format .png
```

then the output pngs don't use the alpha channel.  If I open `TheCompressonator.exe`, select Edit-->create alpha channel,and then select file to save original to png, the png file contains alpha channel, but I have a lot of dds files which need to be converted.

Comment: Dr. Doofensmirtz would be proud.

Comment: ...,!!! :(((((((((((((((

Comment: The tag `dds` has been removed (twice) because that refers to Data Distribution Service, not the dds file format. Please do not put it back in again.